# MySQL equal operator truncates values and does not work as expected

Tags: mysql, equals, operator-keyword

I've just discovered a **strange behaviour of MySQL, about the equal operator**.

In my table example, I have a row with id = 914.
When I run the following request:

```
select * from example where id='914z';
```

MySQL returns the row with id = 914.

Why???
**I mean... '914' is NOT '914z' !**
I believe that this is completely not normal.
If you don't, please tell me why, I'd be happy to discuss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works exactly as it should, and the behaviour is documented. [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html) has good examples:

> The following examples illustrate conversion of strings to numbers
>   for comparison operations:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT 1 > '6x'; -> 0
> mysql> SELECT 7 > '6x'; -> 1
> mysql> SELECT 0 > 'x6'; -> 0
> mysql> SELECT 0 = 'x6'; -> 1
> ```

Comment: `'914z'` is cast to a number for the purpose of the comparison with `id` (assuming `id` is a numeric type). `'914z'` becomes `914` when cast into a number.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I got that, but well, this is quite dangerous for an equality comparison. :/